# Not able to output sound on USB-C port, via USB-C to 3.5 mm aux, on MacBook Pro 13" 2018

Tags: audio, usb, headphones

I'm not able to get any sound when connecting a pair of 3.5 mm headphones through a USB-C to AUX adaptor (so on any of the USB-C ports).

When plugged in, I can immediately see in sound settings that it is recognized and I can select it as an input/output, but when I do so I still get no sound from it.

I use a Samsung USB-C to AUX adapter which has its own DAC. I have another adapter without DAC but that one doesn't even get recognized by my Mac. I often work on my Windows partition (Bootcamp) and it works flawlessly, plug and play, so it clearly isn't a hardware issue. I don't use the 3.5 mm port because I get cracking noise from it.

I am on the 2018 13" MacBook Pro, with Monterey version 12.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your description I would agree this is a software issue.  The problem appears that macOS lacks the correct drivers for your Samsung adapter.  The only solution may be to get a different adapter since it is unlikely anyone is going to fix this driver issue.  The Apple USB-C to 1/8" adapter works for me in macOS and Windows (as well as Linux) and so should work for you.  Given the adapter is listed for $9 this isn't a huge investment to test the theory and possibly resolve the issue.

I can sympathize with the audio quality issues on the 1/8" jack as they are known to wear out or get damaged easily, and can pick up noise from within the computer.  Apple does very well in making durable hardware but that doesn't mean things will never break.  I've dealt with this myself and found USB audio adapters a simple and inexpensive solution.  What I have not seen before myself is a software issue like you describe.

I'd recommend the Apple adapter.  Apple describes it as a solution for iPads and iPhones but it appears to work just fine on macOS and Windows computers as well.  Any adapter should work but as you discovered should does not mean it will.